# calculation in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i want to get the percentage of two decimal values. it is giving correct result individually but when i add two resultant values it gives wrong result. please check where i'm wrong. i'm sharing my code

```
public decimal GetTotal()
    {

        decimal? total = 0;
        decimal? total2 = 0;

        decimal? count = 0;
        decimal? count2 = 0;
        decimal? result = 0;
        decimal? loopcount = 0;
        decimal? result1 = 0;
        decimal? result2 = 0;


        total = _db.Carts.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId).Select(c => ((int?)c.Count * c.Part.Price)).Sum();
        total2 = _db.Carts.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId).Select(c => ((int?)c.Count * c.CustomerPrice)).Sum();

        var cartList = _db.Carts.Where(c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId).ToList();

        foreach (var item in cartList)
        {

            count = total2.HasValue && item.Percentage.HasValue ? ((total2 / 100) * item.Percentage) - total2 : decimal.Zero; // 960
            count2 = total.HasValue && item.Percentage.HasValue ? ((total / 100) * item.Percentage) - total : decimal.Zero;
            loopcount++;
            result1 += ((-1) * count);
            result2 += ((-1) * count2);
            result += result1.Value + result2.Value;

        }                       
        return result ?? decimal.Zero;            
    }
```

i want to add like 960+432=1392 but it is giving 3696, please check

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your problem is the that you're reusing the `result` variables within your for loop. When you write:

```
result1 += ((-1) * count);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result1 = result1 + ((-1) * count);
```

So whatever value `result1` had before this point is added to `((-1) * count)` and the result is assigned back to `result1`. You probably have similar issues with `result2` and `result`.

The solution is to clear the variables (reset them back to 0) after you're done using them so that the previous values do not affect the later calculations or declare the temporary variables within the for loop to be used only within the scope that they are needed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can u please tell me how can i do this by code?what do i need to change?

Comment: and i have declared the variables with 0 before

Comment: @UsamaSheikh I've tried to provide hints about what needs to change, but it's very difficult to tell the correct code would look like without seeing more context. Where are `count` and `total` coming from? What are you doing with `result`? Can you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: will u please tell me now?

Comment: @UsamaSheikh The code is *very* confusing. I'm not sure what it is supposed to do, and I'm pretty sure it would never work as intended. Can you explain exactly what you want this code to calculate (and provide examples)

Comment: i want to get the percentage and sum up that percentage and display the result of sum

Comment: @UsamaSheikh Sorry, I still don't know what that means. Percentage of what? Out of what? If you can show what an example of what in a single `Cart` record and explain what you expect the result to be, maybe I can help you.

Comment: @p.s.w.g gave you a possible reason as to why your results are not what you expected.  If you change it to:   result1 = ((-1) * count); and result2 = ((-1) * count2); you will have your problem solved.

Comment: @p.s.w.g thanks for try but i have changed it to as u wrote, but now i'm getting 2904 but desired result is 1392 :(

Comment: @UsamaSheikh Like I said, please provide a sample data set as well as what result you expect.

Comment: @p.s.w.g can u tell me your skype id? so that i can show u what exactly it is.

Comment: @UsamaSheikh Sorry, I'm not sure I want to publicize my personal Skype id. Furthermore, questions and answers should be available to everybody. Please edit your question to include the relevant information. That way, even if I'm not able to help you, someone else may.